# Get module label from module definition

Tags: spring, spring-xd

Is there any way to get the label (if any) in a Spring XD custom module?

so, if I define a stream like this `time | label:my-module | log`

Could I grab the String label somewhere in my code, as it can be done with module type, or name via:

```
@Value("${xd.module.name}")
private String name;
@Value("${xd.module.type}")
private String value;
//??? is there a xd property (not in the documentation at least)
private String label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, although it is not documented at all it looks like the variable `xd.module.label` is actually exposed out of the box.

I checked out the code to see the real amount of variables (more reliable that the documentation unfortunately) [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-module-spi/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/module/options/spi/ModulePlaceholders.java).